# Pandas: getting specific column from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample `.csv` file:

```
str_header  int_header
string_a       1
string_b       2
string_c       3
```

According to solutions on the internet, this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("z.csv", names=['int_header'])
print(data['int_header'])
```

should only read `int_header` column into `data`. But `data`, when printed as above, actually contains all of the file columns. I'm using Anaconda distribution of Python. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this instead:

```
data = pd.read_csv("z.csv", usecols=['int_header'])
```

assuming that your CSV file has `,` as a delimiter

Explanation:

[Docs:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **names :** array-like, default None
>
> List of column names to use. If file
>    contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None
>
> **usecols :** array-like, default None
>
> Return a subset of the columns. Results > in much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

documentation is a bit confusing.

`names` - used for naming (giving columns names), especially if you don't have a header line or want to ignore/skip it.

`usecols` - used for choosing only "interesting" columns

Comment: The docs confused me: 
names : array-like, default None
List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None
So I thought this is the one to use...

Comment: The "names" argument is for the internal names used by pandas not the actual columns in the csv file.

Comment: @student1, i've added some explanation to my answer